# Field validation on 'optional' field

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to have a field that is allowed to be empty, however, if there is an input, there can only be letters and spaces.

```js
if (!fields["cuisine"]) {
  formIsValid = false;
  errors["cuisine"] = "Cannot be empty";
}
if (typeof fields["cuisine"] !== "undefined") {
  if (!fields["cuisine"].match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
    formIsValid = false;
    errors["cuisine"] = "Only letters";
  }
}
```

I was this, except where formIsValid - false, I basically want that to be true. The issue is if I set it to true, I can throw in numbers and symbols, which I don't want.

Edit:

Here is what I'm working with.

```html
handleValidation() {
        let fields = this.state.fields;
        let errors = {};
        let formIsValid = true;

        //Cuisine
        if (typeof fields["cuisine"] !== "undefined") {
            if (!fields["cuisine"].match(/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/)) {
              formIsValid = false;
              errors["cuisine"] = "Only letters";
            }
          }
    }

<label>Change Cuisine Type:</label>
 <input 
 ref="cuisine" 
 type="text" 
 onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "cuisine")} 
 value={this.state.fields["cuisine"]} 
 placeholder={`${this.props.restCuisine}`}></input>
```

I want inputs like... French, american, etc... I do not want inputs like French2, @merican, etc... But I also want the option for there to be an empty input.

Comment: Uh, if you want to allow empty values, don't use the `if (!fields["cuisine"]) {…}` block?!

Comment: @Bergi I was trying to get my idea across. But it doesn't work without it.

Comment: Please give us some example `fields` input values and the respective expected outcome, so that we can reproduce the problem ourselves.

Comment: @Bergi edited original post

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/` does not match empty strings. Do you want `/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/`?